# Debugging an unknown Linux box

Tags: linux, debugging

I have a Linux box that I have root access to, using SSH.

I want to use GDB to debug the system.

It's a stripped-down Debian package; therefore, I don't have any compile tools in it.

`uname -a` gives:

```
2.6.38.6-41 SMP XXXXXXX 2014 i686 GNU/Linux
```

What is the best way to install GDB on it?
I have tried to download the GDB binaries i386, but it always require a different library installed, so if I install all the compatible libraries asked for gdb then I may corrupt the original system.

How can I achieve the GDB instalation goal?

Thanks

---

**There is no apt-get executable installed.
There is no compiler tools installed.
No file in /etc/lsb_release.**

Comment: Since it's a Debian box, can't you just do `apt-get install gdb`?  What's in `/etc/lsb_release`?

Comment: What do you mean "GDB to debug the system"?

Comment: Would it be possible/practical to compile it on another computer and transfer the binary?

Comment: The easiest way to install gdb is to use the package manager that's available on the system. Since apt-get is not installed, possibly it's not a debian based distribution - you should try to first figure out what it is, and then it would be a lot easier to find help for that distro. If you can't figure it out, you can just copy the binaries of gdb, but as you noticed you will also need all dependencies as well (without using a package manager, there is no easy way to get around this).

Answer (score 0):

If you have Debian package then you can install gdb using following command

sudo apt-get install gdb

Comment: The linux box dont have apt-get installed, neighter any compiling tools.

Comment: Do you have any /etc/debian_version file?